# If a monotone sequence diverges then it does not have converging sub- sequence. prove or provide a counter example.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

As far as I know, if a monotone sequence diverges, it approaches infinity as “n” approaches infinity. Intutively, it si clear to me that a diverging monotone sequence cannot have a convergent sub sequence as we can always find an element of the subsequence lying beyond its limit point. But, I am a bit a skeptical about its formal presentation. please help me with this.

Comment: If a monotone increasing sequence ever goes above some $M$, then it stays above $M$, i.e. only finitely many points lie below $M$. Otherwise, it never goes above $M$, in which case the monotone convergence theorem applies.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a_m)$ be a monotonic increasing diverging sequence; it is said to converge  to $+\infty$.

Recall

$\tag 1 \displaystyle{\lim _{m\to \infty }a_{m}= +\infty} \text{ iff for every integer } N \text{ there exist a term } a_n \text{ such that } a_n \gt N$

Let $(a_{m_k})$ be a subsequence; it is also monotonic increasing. Let the 'challenge'  integer $N$ be given. Select a term $a_n \gt N$. By definition of a subsequence, there is a term $a_{n_k}$ with $n_k \gt n$. Since $(a_m)$ is monotonic increasing, $\, a_n \le a_{n_k}$ and so $a_{n_k} \gt N$. It follows that

$\tag 2 \displaystyle{\lim _{m_k\to \infty }a_{m_k}= +\infty}$

There is a symmetric argument that handles the case when $(a_m)$ is a monotonic decreasing sequence converging to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition we have that

$$a_n\to \infty \iff\forall M \quad \exists n_0 \quad \forall n\ge n_0 \quad a_n\ge M$$

therefore for any $a_{k_n}$ with $k_n \to \infty $

$$\exists n_1 \quad \forall n\ge n_1 \quad k_n\ge n_0 \quad a_{k_n}\ge M$$

As an alternative, suppose $\exists a_{k_n}\to L<\infty$ that is

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists n_2 \quad \forall n\ge n_2 \quad |a_{k_n}-L|\ge \epsilon$$

and take $\epsilon =1$ and $M=L+100$ therefore

$$\exists n\ge n_2 \quad a_n< M$$

which is a contradiction.